# Multi level routing in express js

Tags: node.js, express

I am developing **simple** CMS application in Express.
The admin can configure his routes like this:

domain/f1/f2/f3/f4/page1(will render page1 view)

domain/n1/n2/page2 (will render page2 view)

So basically, as far as i know i cannot use static controllers.

Should i use router.get * to catch all routes (and then goto db to get the view i want to render)?
What is the right and best practice approach for this kind of dynamic routing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use asterisk to match any route that ends with `page1` and then render the according view:

```
// match routes that ends with 'page1'
app.get('/*/page1', function (req, res) {
    res.render('page1');
});
```

Or you can set route handler as a variable and then use it to handle multiple routes:

```
// create page1 route handler 
var hadnlePage1 = function (req, res) {
    res.render('page1');
}

app.get('/definePage1Route/:route', function (req, res) {

    // GET /definePage1Route/f1%2Ff2%2Ff3%2Ff4%2Fpage1
    // req.param.route => /f1/f2/f3/f4/page1
    app.get(req.params.route, handlePage1);

    res.end('done');

});
```